# Replace character if not preceeded by same character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to escape some backslash's by replacing a single `\` with `\\`:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = REPLACE(Column , '\', '\\')
```

But I would like to do the replace only if the backslash is not precedent by another backslash, so that input `test\` should replace to `test\\` but `test\\` should stay `test\\`.

If more than two backslash are present it shouldn't replace either.

Comment: Could you have `'test\\\'`? If so, what happens then?

Comment: Easiest way would be nested replaces. One to double up all \ and then the outer one to find all instances of \\\\ and replace with \\

Comment: @Larnu would do nothing either, forgot to add that info. Will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL doesn't support pattern replacements, so you'll need to use a few nested `REPLACE`s here; the first to replace the double slashes (`\\`) to something that doesn't appear in your data (I use a pipe (`|`)), the second to replace the single slashes, and then finally a 3rd to replace the pipes back to double slashes.

```sql
UPDATE dbo.[Table]
SET [Column] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column], '\\', '|'),'\','\\'),'|','\\');
```

If you have a value like `'test\\\'` this will end up as `'test\\\\'`, as the first 2 `\` characters would not be replaced, but the latter would.

---

As I am a "glutton for punishment", if you do need to avoid the above scenario of `'\\\'` being replaced to `'\\\\'` *and* (because you don't mention) could have multiple instances of single slashes in your values, you would have to do something like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Table] (ID int IDENTITY, --As I assume you have some kind of ID column
                         [Column] varchar(100));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.[Table] ([Column])
VALUES ('test\'),
       ('sample\\'),
       ('example\\\'),
       ('Another\example'),
       ('A\harder\\example\'),
       ('A\far\\more\complex\\example\\\than\is\\needed\');
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Table];
GO
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT T.ID,
           T.[Column],
           PI.I,
           STUFF(T.[Column],PI.I+1,0,'\') AS NewColumn,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM dbo.[Table] T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^\]\[^\]%',[Column])))PI(I)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ID,
           r.[Column],
           PI.I,
           LEFT(r.NewColumn,r.I+1) + STUFF(S.StuffColumn,PI.I+1,0,'\') AS NewColumn,
           r.Iteration+1 AS Iteration
    FROM rCTE r
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(r.NewColumn,1,r.I+1,'')))S(StuffColumn)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^\]\[^\]%',StuffColumn)))PI(I)
    WHERE PI.I > 0)
UPDATE T
SET [Column] = CASE WHEN r.NewColumn LIKE '%[^\]\' THEN r.NewColumn + '\' ELSE r.NewColumn END
FROM dbo.[table] T
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)
                         CASE WHEN r.NewColumn LIKE '%[^\]\' THEN r.NewColumn + '\' ELSE r.NewColumn END AS NewColumn
                  FROM rCTE r
                  WHERE r.ID = T.ID
                  ORDER BY r.Iteration DESC) r;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Table];
```

Here we have to use a recursive CTE to iterate through the value, and each time it find a slash (`\`) that doesn't have another slash adjacent to it it injects another into the string. Then, as that doesn't work at the *end* of the string, you would need to use a `CASE` expression to add the value the extra slash at the end. You'd also need to do this for the start (but I haven't done that here).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f83545f974f25ca3de8c2cd51f45b29)

Comment: Seems good, will try it to see how that works out.

Comment: That edit was brilliant, not only for the specific answer but also to general SQL knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, rather than doing that mess I did there, you'd likely be better off looking at Regex CLR functions if you had to do something like that, @iamdlm .